# Cannot resolve symbol getReadableDatabse in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

[image: I can't seem to make this work. I am copying a youtube video tutorial about SQLite database in android studio and I encountered this error. Can someone please help? Thanks!]

I can't seem to make this work. I am copying a youtube video tutorial about SQLite database in android studio and I encountered this error. Can someone please help? Thanks!

```
public class DataListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    UserDBHelper userDBHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplication(), R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
   userDBHelper = new UserDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = new userDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDBHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String Fname, Lname, Email, Password, Contact, Address;
            Fname = cursor.getString(0);
            Lname = cursor.getString(1);
            Email = cursor.getString(2);
            Password = cursor.getString(3);
            Contact = cursor.getString(4);
            Address = cursor.getString(5);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(Fname, Lname, Email, Password, Contact, Address);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());


    }


}
```

}

Comment: build and clean the project. and make sure userDBHelper class extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: pls post some code. your screen shot does not help. Also your activity needs to extend AppCompatActivity. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: @bharat I tried cleaning it but the error is still there. It says "package userDBHelper does not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a misplaced `new`:

```
sqLiteDatabase = new userDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Remove it - you want to call the `getReadableDatabase()` method on the `userDBHelper` object, not create a new instance of `userDBHelper.getReadableDatabase` class that doesn't exist.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that sir? I'm quite new to this and I'm just following an instructional video on Youtube. Thanks

Comment: Android Studio includes a text editor. Put the cursor at the `new` and delete it.

Comment: The error is now gone! Thank you very much sir! I created a new instance when I should just call it from the method. Thanks!